# Brightness hotkey doesn't work properly on my hardware

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, brightness

I have a System 76 Gazelle Pro notebook.

Sound hotkeys work correctly but not brightness one.
When I push Fn+F8, it displays the ubuntu notification about brightness going down but the real brightness (actual quantity of lignt) doesn't go lower. For Fn+F9 (brightness up), the notification appears but doensn't increment, nor the real brightness go high).

By reading [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) and [that](https://superuser.com/questions/471323), I got few informations but don't know what to do.

Thank you !

Comment: And what have you tried about this and that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using terminal & typing `xrandr' produces

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 260mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       85.0     75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        85.1     72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        85.0     72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Now see my VGA1 is connected (I have a dual display) so we need to change its brightness
use:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.7
```

one can change 0.7 to anything but 0! Also you can make this a default startup script

Update:
Brightness Control key re-enable

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

then save and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart the system for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Now I an control brightness, but it's a quite dirty hack (scripts or custom shortcuts), is it possible to modify some files in the system to make the FN keys working properly ? and if not, where do I have to go (forum, mailing list...) to help developers support my system/hardware ?

Comment: see the updated reply.